# Solve the Peg and Hole Game

Tags: algorithm

The peg puzzle is often found on tables in Cracker Barrel restaurants in the South. The board 
starts with 15 holes and 14 pegs, so one hole is left empty. Players proceed by jumping over 
pegs into empty holes, removing the jumped peg each time. Solving the puzzle means ending 
with just one peg in the original empty hole.

Example:

```
X-pegs O-hole

    O <- Position A
   X X
  X X X <- move that peg to position A
 X X X X
X X X X X

    X <- Position A
   X O <-That peg is removed
  X X O 
 X X X X
X X X X X
```

It's not the classical 14-peg puzzle. I want to know in an arbitrary situation is it possible to change it to the situation that just one peg in the original empty hole?

Comment: Related: [Solve the 14-Pegs puzzle](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5574/solve-the-14-pegs-puzzle)

Comment: It's easier to solve if you start from the peg in the top position and work backwards.  Jump over a hole and put the peg back in.  A brute force depth search will find an answer quick enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 32768 possible positions in this game (15 holes, each of which can have a peg or not). Build a graph where each node is a position, and each vector is a possible transition from one position to another. Then search the graph for a path between the two nodes you are interested in.

After you build this graph, it would be interesting (and easy) to determine whether any starting positions are unwinnable (not including positions which are trivially unwinnable by having "isolated" pegs which no other peg can reach).

Comment: Of course there are unwinnable positions, otherwise the game would not make much sense. If you mean only positions with 14 pegs, then that's an interesting question.

Comment: @n.m. do you think there might be an unwinnable positions with 14 pegs? Wouldn't be much of a game then either.

Comment: There are less possible states than you suggest. 2^14 is the most possible and I suspect not all of them are reachable.

Comment: @n.m: All of the 14-peg starting positions are winnable. There are actually only 4 unique starting positions. The others are mirrors or rotations of those four.

Comment: @Jodrell: That's a good point. I think it is easier to build a complete graph of all 2^15 board configurations, though, rather than trying to determine in advance which positions are reachable. Also note that even with only 14 pegs, the number of possible states is more than 2^14, since pegs can jump into the initially empty hole.

Comment: @AlexD, after the first move, 2 pegs are removed. As Jim Mischel points out you can do a rotational transform on all starting position to radically condense the graph.

Comment: OK, another good point! If you want to solve peg and hole games FAST, this is the way to do it. This would be a good place to use something like Zobrist hashing... XOR the signatures of the current board AND all of its mirrors/rotations, then use that as key into a lookup table to avoid adding redundant nodes to the graph.

Comment: There are indeed unreachable positions. For example, you can't have three vacant corners, and pegs in the other 12 holes. Based on a quick and dirty program that does an exhaustive depth-first search, it appears that somewhat less than half (about 14,000) of the 2^15 possible positions are actually reachable.

Comment: Wow, this is some pretty heavy-duty algorithmic analysis here for peg and hole games... I guess that's liable to happen when programmers start trying to impress each other! :D Seriously, though, @JimMischel, that's a very interesting result; thanks for taking the trouble to actually write the program and check!

Comment: This could be an interesting programming challenge for one of those programming puzzle sites, or even a competition: solving huge peg-and-hole games (think thousands of pegs).